# Python Matplotlib Table Implementation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a table in matplotlib. I've done it before but it's been awhile and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong this time. Here is what I've tried:

Note: I'm using the `plot.subplots()` method because in actuality I will be creating multiple axes for my own purposes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
fig,ax = plot.subplots()
rows = ['1']
columns = ['1','2']
cell_text = ['a','b']
table = ax.table(cellText = cell_text, rowLabels = rows, colLabels = columns)
```

Which results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5372, in table
    return mtable.table(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/table.py", line 509, in table
    assert len(rowLabels) == rows
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell_text` should be a 2D array

```
cell_text = [['a','b']]
```